# Proving $ \int_E f \, d\mu=\int_X f\,\chi_E\, d\mu $ .

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory

Let $f\in(X,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{R}_+)$ and let $E\in\mathcal{F}$. Then
$$ \int_E f \,~d\mu=\int_X f\,\chi_E\,~d\mu. $$

**Proof.** According to Big Rudin's Definition 1.23(page 19) of integration of positive functions we have 
$$ \int_E f\,d\mu=\sum_{j=1}^m \alpha_j\mu(E\cap A_j), $$
with $A_1,\ldots,A_m\in\mathcal{F}$ and $\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_m\in[0,+\infty]$. 
Now, 
$$ \int_E f\,d\mu=\sum_{j=1}^m \alpha_j\mu(E\cap A_j)+\sum_{j=m}^m 0\cdot \mu(E^c\cap A_j)=\sum_{j=1}^m\alpha_j\mu((E\cup E^c)\cap A_j)\chi_E=\sum_{j=1}^m\alpha_j\mu(X\cap A_j)\chi_E=\int_X f\chi_E~d\mu.  $$
Is this proof correct?

Comment: Something is missing, are you assuming that $f$ is a simple function?

Comment: General strategy is to do this for step functions (as you already did) and then applying Monotone convergence theorem.

Comment: Is the definition $\int_E f d\mu = \int_X f d\mu|_{E}$ where $\mu|_E(A) = \mu(A\cap E)$?

Comment: I'm assuming $f=\sum_j^m\alpha_j\chi_{A_j}$, where $\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_m$ are distinct values of $f$.

Comment: I don't have the book, but that is just the integral of a simple function.

Comment: Rudin's definition of integral for general measurable function formally is based on $sup$ of integrals for simple functions. What would you like to proof  - $$\int_E f\,d\mu = \int_X f \chi_E \,d\mu $$ ?

Comment: I was trying to prove it for simple positive functions. Is the subsection (f) of the Proposition 1.24 on Big Rudin's book.

Answer (score 3):

Approximate $f$ with a sequence of simple functions $f_n\nearrow f$, i.e., $f_n:=\sum_{j=1}^n\alpha_j\chi_{A_j}$. Then
$$
\int_E f_n\,d\mu =\sum_{j=1}^n \alpha_j \mu(E\cap A_j) =\sum_{j=1}^n \alpha_j \mu(X\cap (E\cap A_j))=\int _X f_n\chi_E\,d\mu
$$
because $f_n\chi_E = \sum_{j=1}^n\alpha_j\chi_{A_j}\chi_E=\sum_{j=1}^n\alpha_j\chi_{E\cap A_j}$. Now send $n\to\infty$.